# What events will trigger an auto-save?

Tags: far-cry-3

What events will trigger an auto-save? This is so the player can better decide when to save manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I noticed that the game automatically saves:

- After buying or selling from a store
- When you have reached a checkpoint in a quest
- When you have finished a quest
- When you enter a [quest area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77jNX.jpg)
- After you liberate an outpost

Quest is defined here as a story-mission, a mission from the job board at outposts (hunting, assassination) or a Trial of the Rakyat challenge.

Comment: @Strike In my game (PC), I don't see the auto-save icon when I take a letter (collectible). Are you sure about that edit? What about the other collectibles?

Comment: I just checked it ingame and I'm sorry to say that my edit is indeed incorrect. I got it confused with the experience bar that pops up when you take a collectible. I'm sorry for the confusion. I will suggest an edit to remove that point, add another and define things a bit more clearly.

Comment: @Strike Are you also sure about the edit regarding an auto-save after liberating an outpost? After I liberate outposts in the second island, I don't see the auto-save icon.

Comment: For me in the very least it worked. As soon as the little cutscene was over the auto-save icon popped up. Take [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5XgyGSAbXE) at 5:23 for reference.

Comment: @Strike I see. I must have just missed it.